# Akka multiple actor systems vs multiple child actors and GUI

Tags: akka, akka-http

I am trying to develop an application where each node performs a set of tasks: N nodes, each node performs task A, task B etc. The tasks are not distributed. The plan I have come up with is to come up with a single actor system on each node. For each task an actor is created. The tasks will be triggered on the remote systems by a main controller node. I want to know whether this is the right approach.

The nodes are distributed. Is it better to go for a cluster approach or just remoting. Also what are the approaches to launch the tasks on the remote systems from the main controller via a GUI(web based),ie. interacting with actors from GUI. Is it using akka-http or something else.

Comment: I have posted an answer if you want any clarification then fill free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is better to go for a cluster. If you use cluster then it is good idea to have a master node in between all the nodes. It means no other nodes can directly communicate with each other all nodes can communicate each other through master node, master node keep routing information of all the nodes. If you are requesting any task to your web services through gui, then it is required to have a actor system on your web services node, then your flow is like this you send request from gui to webservices node it send reqeust to master node, master node sends request to worker node and worker node process your request.